# How to make redis comand SLAVEOF work for encrypted redis master?

Tags: redis

I started two redis node separately with original redis.conf, which I don't want to edit it, however I want to use redis command, such as slaveof, to config redis nodes dynamically.

If redis nodes without 'auth', i.e. no "requirepass" in the redis.conf, the following command on the slave redis node will work:

```
redis-server --slaveof redis-master 6379
```

where redis-master is the hostname of the redis master node.

But this will not work if the master is encrypted. I've went through the redis official docs, nothing helps. Before I go for antirez, I want to hear from you here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `masterauth` config to specify the master's password.

1. start `redis-cli` to connect to the slave instance.
2. set `masterauth` config: `config set masterauth master-password`
3. set master: `slaveof redis-master master-port`

Comment: you are totally right. I did not find the command working thru config :)
Eventually, I run these two command in the sentinel node to bind these 3 nodes together: 
redis-cli -h slave -a master-password config set masterauth master-password;
redis-cli -h slave -a masterpassword slaveof redis-master 6379

Comment: https://redis.io/topics/replication#setting-a-replica-to-authenticate-to-a-master